# Composer not installing Fork CMS on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, composer-php

I have Windows 10, actual XAMPP and actual Composer.
Fork CMS is under E:\xampp\htdocs\fork. In this directory there is a composer.json file with the following lines:

```
...
     "scripts": {
            "post-install-cmd": "php app/console assetic:dump . && cd tools && bash ./remove_cache",
            "post-update-cmd": "php app/console assetic:dump . && cd tools && bash ./remove_cache"
        },
...
```

When I run "composer install" in this directory I get the following error:

> [RuntimeException] Error Output: Command "bash" is misspelled or not
>   found (* translated from German)

Anyone has a clue for me? I know that bash is from linux, but I don't know how it can be used in my circumstances. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is as clear as it can get: There is no `bash` command available on your machine. This is a very likely error, as Windows systems don't have a `bash` command.

So the solution is easy to find as well: Install the `bash` command. Git by windows comes with a bash command for instance. [Other solutions are also available](https://superuser.com/a/608107/484166).

Comment: This helped me out! Thank you so much.